# window.open doesn't focus window in chrome extension when jquery ui library included

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, focus, window.open

I am using `window.open` to open a popup window in my Chrome extension. This works fine. But, when I include jquery-ui.js (v1.11.4) in my extension, the popup window does not focus once opened. It flashes in the foreground for a second and then moves to the background. I have tried using `window.focus` but I think that doesn't work in Chrome (even the workaround of using `window.blur` didn't work).

Same thing happens if I try to create a popup with `chrome.windows.create`. I'm not sure why this problem occurs only when the the jquery ui library is included. Is this a known bug?

UPDATED:
My code flow is as follows:

popup.html

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
     .....
</body>
```

login.js

```
displayPopup();
function displayPopup() {
   var popupWin = window.open(url, '', 'height=800, width=800, scrollbars=scroll');
   if (window.focus) {
      console.log('window has focus');
      popupWin.focus();
   }
   else if (popupWin.focus) {
       console.log('popup has focus');
   }
}
```

I can see that window has focus because `console.log('window has focus');` is being printed. But, the `popupWin.focus();` doesn't seem to be executing.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to show the offending code, as no, it's not a known problem but something to do with your code. Also, consider updating the window to make it focused with `tabs` API.

Comment: @Xan, thanks for confirming. As I mentioned, I tried chrome.windows.create and chrome.windows.update, and that didn't work either. I have included my code above.

Comment: Using `window.open` from extensions is not recommended. Can you show your `tabs` attempt instead?

Comment: @Xan, I debugged this further, and it turns out that including the jquery-ui.js library in popup.html header is causing problems. If I copy-paste the library directly in login.js, it's fine. Should I be using chrome messaging instead or something else?